# VLC crash troubleshooting on 16.04

Tags: vlc, crash

VLC has been working however it now crashes when tasked to play a video.

- .mp3 .m4a files (not associated to VLC) do NOT crash and play on VLC
- .mkv .mp4 files crash VLC

VLC was removed and reinstalled:

```
sudo apt-get remove vlc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Version: vlc_2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb

FFMPEG plays videos.

What tests can be performed to identify the issue's root cause?

Update: VLC was invoked from the command line and tasked to play a video.  The crash results include:

```
user@hostname:~$ vlc
VLC media player 2.2.7 Umbrella (revision 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1)
[0000000000a09148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0000000000b16d28] dbus interface error: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
[0000000000b16d28] dbus interface error: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
[0000000000b16d28] dbus interface error: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
[0000000000b16d28] dbus interface error: poll() failed: Interrupted system call
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Does the same file plays with other players?

Comment: Good question:  I'm unable to find the default 'Video' application, so ffmpeg was installed an videos play from commandline: VLC continues to crash on videos.